# Paypal API Implementation using PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have developed a freelancing website, where client can pay through paypal

but I am confused how to check client has paid for which job?

System is redirecting user to paypal interface where he pays and returns back, now to store payment transaction information I have implemented IPN

but How would i know client has paid for which job

for eg If I have following database schema for transaction

id, user_id, job_id, trans_id

How would I get job_id while saving transaction id?

is there any concept of custom fields?

Comment: May be you can also use in  get method of reutrn url or  ex: your_returnurl/job_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the custom field in IPN. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609678/passing-and-parse-paypal-ipn-custom-field)

[From documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/)

> custom    Custom value as passed by you, the merchant. These are
>   pass-through variables that are never presented to your customer
>   Length: 255 characters