# Passing array through PayPal IPN

Tags: php, html, arrays, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have an array which looks like this:

```
array(0 => $website_ref,1 => $user_id,2 => $item1,3 => $item2,4 => $item3,5 => $item4);
```

And I have tried multiple times, different ways to pass it through this PayPal button code like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<? array(0 => $website_ref,1 => $user_id,2 => $item1,3 => $item2,4 => $item3,5 => $item4); ?>">
```

So on the `IPN.php` it can be read like this:

```
$custom = $_POST['custom'];

$website_ref = $custom[0];
$user_id = $custom[1];
$item1 = $custom[2];
$item2 = $custom[3];
$item3 = $custom[4];
$item4 = $custom[5];
```

But I'm fairly sure I'm doing something wrong as the code isn't working. I have tried using the array in a variable and passing that through but on the other side my first result was 'A' probably for 'Array'. I know I'm missing something here but not too sure how to get it working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing and Parse PayPal IPN Custom field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609678/passing-and-parse-paypal-ipn-custom-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['custom']` is returning a value that is the String version of the array.  I.e the same as if you did `echo array(...)`.  `$_POST['custom']` will always be a string, which is why you are getting `A` when you do `$custom[0]`.

When setting the value of the custom element you most likely want to format it in a way that you then parse the data when you receive it back from PayPal.

You could potentially use [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) as the format, or have a look at [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609678/passing-and-parse-paypal-ipn-custom-field) for other options.

Using JSON the implementation would be:

```
<?php
  $arr = array($website_ref, $user_id, $item1, $item2, $item3, $item4);
  $data = json_encode($arr);
?>
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?= $data ?>">
```

Then in IPN.php:

```
$custom = json_decode($_POST['custom'], true);

$website_ref = $custom[0];
$user_id = $custom[1];
$item1 = $custom[2];
$item2 = $custom[3];
$item3 = $custom[4];
$item4 = $custom[5];
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that the custom paramter is limited to 256 characters.  If you run into problems with that you could always save necessary data to a database table, pass the ID of the record into the custom parameter, and then pull that data back out using the ID within the IPN script.